# Rename All Files in a Directory with consecutive numbers in Python

Tags: python

I would like to rename all file (the filenames have no clear pattern) into filenames with consecutive numbers e.g:

Files in Directory:

agh_uio78.jpg
hhaq23klp.png
mickey.tiff

into

001.jpg
002.png
003.tiff

This will give me a result with no extension:

```
import os

FList = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
FListC = FList[1:]

m = 0
for i in FListC:
    os.rename(i,str(m))
    m = m+1
```

Result:

1
2
3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import os

FList = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
FListC = FList[1:]

m = 0
for i in FListC:
    fileExtension = os.path.splitext(i)[1]
    os.rename(i,str(m)+fileExtension)
    m = m+1
```

You forgot to save the extension of the file.
Above code will grab the file's extension and concatenate to your incremented file name

Comment: Might not work for files like `*.tar.gz`. Also, shouldn't it be `splitext(i)[1]`?

Comment: Awesome works. I have an additional question. If I leave my script in the directory it will be renamed as well. Is there any way to let the user choose the directory instead of "os.getcwd()" ?

Comment: You can even shorten it to `for m, i in enumerate(FListC):`.

Comment: In case, if the files are in a format like `*.tar.gz` then using `splitext(i)[-1]` command would work fine in getting the extension.